# Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

````
const elem = document.getElementById("email") as HTMLCanvasElement;
const width = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("width");
const height = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("height");
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log(width, height)
   },[elem, width, height]);```
````

If I put the consts inside the `useEffect` it weirdly works, but can't do it, I need have it outside and as `useEffect` dependencies.

Comment: debug or use `console.log(elem)`, I think that elem is null

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this component is rendering the `#email` element, `getElementById` is going to run *before the component mounts* and the element won't exist yet.

It works inside `useEffect` because that code runs *after* the component mounts.

From the [useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.